# Unmarshal a string to a map struct using a base template (reverse process of template parse)

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm curious to see if there is a way to marshal a map or struct from a string and a Go Template (the reverse of `template.Execute`)

For example, let's say we have the following template for a filename pattern

```golang
const NameTemplate = `{{ .Os.Type }}/{{ .Os.Variant }}!{{ .Os.Version }}!{{ .Name }}!{{ .Version }}`
```

And let's say we have the following map (using a structure in my solution, but I'll use a map here for simplicity)

```
data := map[string]interface{}{
    "Name": "some-name",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "Os": map[string]interface{}{
        "Type": "linux",
        "Variant": "debian",
        "Version": "9.0",
    },
}
```

Doing a `tmpl.Execute(NameTemplate, data)` will result in `linux/debian!9.0!some-name!1.0`

Now what if we had that string `linux/debian!9.0!some-name!1.0` and the template defined above `NameTemplate`. Is there a simple way to do obtain a map (or struct) like the one defined in `data`?

Comment: No, this is not possible. fmt.Scanf may do something similar for simple enough cases, though.